# Using URL REWRITE to redirect secondary domain to a folder on a hosting account

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have two domains and one hosting account.
I want the new domain to point to a sub-folder in my hosting account.

I've made a "HOST A" redirection for the new domain,
so now when i type SECONDARY.COM (for example) i reach the root of the hosting (the same as if i was typing PRIMART.COM).

I then added a .htaccess file with this content :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^secondary\.co\.il$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.primary.il/secondary$1 [R=301,L]
```

But seems like it changes nothing -
When i type SECONDARY.COM i still reach the root and not the folder ("secondary").

Maybe something about the syntax, can't find the problem.

I've been trying almost anything but with no success,
ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe remove the `!^` from the condition's regex?

Comment: You're right man, the exclamation mark had to go, it's REGEX for "NOT", so i fixed to this but still no go :
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} secondary\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.primary.com/secondary/index.php [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Looks a lot like what you're looking for :).
Footnote: for underneath example primary.com offcourse also has to be a subfolder, which in my opinion is "cleaner".

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  secondary.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/secondary.com/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /secondary.com/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  primary.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/primary.com/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /primary.com/$1 [L]
```

Source: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/rewriting-urls-to-host-multiple-domains-on-a-single-ip-address-with-apache/6042903